# iOS CALayer mask strange half pixel line

Tags: ios, calayer, pixel, cabasicanimation

I need to cut transparent arc from 0 to pi through all text layer.
Code give above below working fine except one thing.
I have small width line while performing CABasicAnimation for masking CALayer and no strange line in idle state.

[half pixel line image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkwiz.png)

Can't understand why it's showing because theoretically it doesn't have to be visible at all...

Here is my playground code:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let rootView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,
                                    width: 200,
                                    height: 200))
rootView.backgroundColor = .gray

let uiview = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                  y: 0,
                                  width: 200,
                                  height: 200))
uiview.setTitle("H", for: .normal)
uiview.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 200)
uiview.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
uiview.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
uiview.layer.cornerRadius = 100
uiview.layer.masksToBounds = true
rootView.addSubview(uiview)

let center = CGPoint(x: uiview.bounds.width / 2,
                     y: uiview.bounds.height / 2)

let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                        radius: 80,
                        startAngle: 0,
                        endAngle: .pi,
                        clockwise: true)
path.append(UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                         radius: 78,
                         startAngle: -1,
                         endAngle: .pi,
                         clockwise: true))
path.append(UIBezierPath(rect: uiview.bounds))

let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
maskLayer.frame = uiview.bounds
maskLayer.path = path.cgPath
maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
maskLayer.lineWidth = 0

uiview.layer.mask = maskLayer

let rotation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
rotation.fromValue = 0.0
rotation.toValue = Double.pi * 2
rotation.duration = 10
rotation.repeatCount = 2
maskLayer.add(rotation, forKey: nil)


PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = rootView
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a few small changes, like so:

```
path.append(UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                         radius: 78,
                         startAngle: .pi,
                         endAngle: 0,
                         clockwise: false))
```

the last few seconds of the animation look like this:

[image: last few seconds of animation]

The two arc were misaligned to each other.

So what changed:

- the second arc got a start angle of PI
- it got an end angle of 0
- clockwise is set to false

Is that what you're looking for?